# Spark streaming read exception - java.net.SocketException; py4j.Py4JNetworkException

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, py4j

I am been using spark streaming to read directly from a Kafka topic. Everything has been fine, but today I started getting this error and I can't figure out what's wrong, been looking everywhere.

```
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: ...
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {KafkaV2[Subscribe[TopicName]]: {"TopicName":{"0":6}}}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
Project [cast(value#95 as string) AS value#108]
+- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#94, value#95, topic#96, partition#97, offset#98L, timestamp#99, timestampType#100], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@7af16b01, KafkaV2[Subscribe[TopicName]]

22/04/19 21:56:28 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [...] terminated with error
py4j.Py4JException: Error while sending a command.
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:397)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:356)
        at py4j.reflection.PythonProxyHandler.invoke(PythonProxyHandler.java:106)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1(ForeachBatchSink.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.PythonForeachBatchHelper$.$anonfun$callForeachBatch$1$adapted(ForeachBatchSink.scala:55)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.sources.ForeachBatchSink.addBatch(ForeachBatchSink.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$17(MicroBatchExecution.scala:600)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:103)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runBatch$16(MicroBatchExecution.scala:598)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runBatch(MicroBatchExecution.scala:598)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:228)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:375)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:373)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:193)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:187)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.$anonfun$runStream$1(StreamExecution.scala:303)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:775)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:286)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:209)
Caused by: py4j.Py4JNetworkException: Error while sending a command: c
p4
call
ro161
L0
e

        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:253)
        at py4j.CallbackClient.sendCommand(CallbackClient.java:384)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
        at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.readBlockingResponse(ClientServerConnection.java:313)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.sendCommand(ClientServerConnection.java:229)
        ... 31 more
Exception: Error while sending a command.
```

I really have no idea what's going on. If anyone has any idea, it would be very much appreciated! Thanks.